# a simple function for return number from string in php

Tags: php, regex, string, numbers, preg-match

I want capture Rank from this code :

```
 $RankStr = 'var trafficstatsSnippet =  "/site/trafficstats;pysa1bpbPOVl6Wm5d4Zv4nKXKdM%3D
 /aahoonet.com/?adult=&category=&rank=1234567";'
```

I use this code :

> ```
> $NewPOS = strpos($RankStr, "rank=");
> $SRank = substr($RankStr, $NewPOS + 5, 10);
> echo $SRank;
> ```

because of RANK code variable from (1 - 25,000,000) , i use above code by selecting maximum 10 charachters after starting position of rank= plus 5 further index.

so this function return

```
1234567";
```

and after that i want to grab this number from string. trying `preg_match_all` or `regex` but becasue of nofamiliarity with these functions i cant gain any usable response.

Please Help me for this problem, If there is more solution  please provide them!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use preg_match as:

```
if(preg_match('/rank=(\d+)/',$RankStr,$m)) {
 $rank = $m[1];
}
```

[**Code in Action**](http://www.ideone.com/5mHvo)