# PHP: Best method to extract numbers from a string

Tags: php, string, preg-match

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [a simple function for return number from string in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4175941/a-simple-function-for-return-number-from-string-in-php)

What's the best/most efficient method to extract a specific set of numbers from a string?  For example: I want to get the set of numbers immediately after Case# in sring "blah blah Case#004522 blah blah".  I imagine the number of numeric characters after Case# will always be the same but I would like the code to not make that assumption as I have been.

So far I have been using a strpos method to locate Case# and then pull a specific number of characters afterwords using substr.  I just feel like this is clunky.  Maybe preg_match would be more effective or simplified?

```
$text = "blah blah Case#004552 blah blah";
$find = strpos($text,'Case#');
if ( $find )
  $numbers = substr($text, $find+5, 6);
```

Comment: `preg_match('/\d+/', $str, $match);` - `$match[0]` will contain the first continuous set of digits in the string.

Comment: Depends on your definition of 'best'. Do you mean fastest? I believe strpos is supposed to be the fastest way of finding a particular string in another string, assuming treating the number as a string to begin with (faster than preg_match).

Comment: @Ryven : Best in this particular case was with preg_match as getting possible multiple matches in an array was an unconsidered bonus.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make use of regular expressions to first match your pattern of characters (`Case#`) and then you expect to match numbers only (digits), that is `\d` in PCRE ([Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/ispV1l)):

```
$numbers = preg_match("/Case#(\d+)/", $text, $matches)
              ? (int)$matches[1]
              : NULL
    ;
unset($matches);
```

For multiple (integer) matches at once:

```
$numbers = preg_match_all("/Case#(\d+)/", $text, $matches)
              ? array_map('intval', $matches[1])
              : NULL
    ;
unset($matches);
```

Comment: You don't need the `[]` in `[\d]`.

Comment: The will emit notices if the regex doesn't match

Comment: I like the fact that this returns an array of possible multiple matches as it fits our scenario very well.  Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can locate it as you do it already, and then scan for the number ([Demo](http://codepad.org/S39Qfa4Q)):

```
$find = strpos($text, 'Case#');
sscanf(substr($text, $find), 'Case#%d', $numbers);
```

Comment: This works as well and it's very simple.  The only reason I would prefer the preg_match example is that it returns possible multiple matches which, until I saw that, hadn't realized that can actually occur in our scenario.  Thank you!

Comment: Yes, if the pattern is more general and you have repetition, `preg_match_all` is a good choice. I edited the other answer and added an example with `preg_match_all`.

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP's preg_match and following regex:

```
(?<=case#)[0-9]+
```

You can test @ http://regexr.com?31jdv

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is

```
if (preg_match('/Case#\s*(\d+)/i', $test, $m)) {
    $numbers = $m[1];
}
```